# Render difference between preview and resulting post

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, editor

If I edit or create a post I get a preview ([take for instance this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28340192/wpf-datagrid-with-multiple-hyperlinks-in-a-cell)). But that preview is differently rendered from the post when actually posted.

First comes the edit preview and then the real view of the post.

[image: diff]

Please make them equal.

Comment: +1 There are other ways to indicate it's a draft aside that wouldn't affect the layout. Even if it might not be the theoretical ideal, people are naturally going to want optimize their posts for the format where 90% of users are going to view them, and this disrupts that.

Answer (score 11):

How do they go about making them equal? The preview has 22px less space to work with because of the padding and border around it that indicates it's the preview. Are you suggesting that the final output should also be 22px less wide so that it can match the preview?

But past that, the preview's width not matching is not a problem, because there are other places where it won't match: the apps and the mobile website. They will all render your post *completely* different than how you're seeing it on the main site because the widths are drastically different.

There's really no simple way to "fix" this, nor is it really necessary to fix.

Comment: Since the new design this is kind of bothering me, because code editing is different. I never noticed that behaviour on the past 3000 post I wrote. Something changed.

Comment: It's always been that way, it's just an incredibly small window where there will be differences. I've noticed in plenty of times in the past where my sentences were just a bit too long in the preview and that one word fell onto a new line, but when posted, it didn't fall onto a new line. The padding might have increased and made the window ever-so-slightly less narrow, but the behavior hasn't changed.

Comment: The apps and the mobile website presumably represent an very small percentage of users. It's natural that people will prioritize the appearance of their posts in the format that 90% of readers will actually see.

Comment: A relatively easy “fix” would be to remove the border and use other means of signaling that the rendered output is a preview such as using a different background color, or putting the border on the outside or doing nothing at all since it should be clear this is a preview anyway.  However, I totally agree that posts should focus on semantically correct markup and not make too many assumptions about the style used to render them because that is subject to change at any time and different on other platforms as you say.